# help for debug my code in jQuery-ajax!?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery

why my code have this error, after click on button submit and click on link search: 
i use of codeigniter.

```
An error has occured:
[object Object]
error
```

and this my Tour_foreign->CI_Controller:

```
function search_customer(){ 
    $customer_number = $this->input->post('customer_number');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('customer_number' => $customer_number));
    if($query->num_rows()==0){
                echo '0';
            }else{
                $data = array();
                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                   $data[] = $row;
                }
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
    }

function insert_customers(){
    $customer_number = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    $customer_number .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    /*////////////////////////////////////*/
    $jdate = jgmdate("j F Y");
        /*////////////////////////////////////*/
        $useradmin = $this->session->userdata('login');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('login', array('useradmin' => $useradmin))->row();
        $nameadmin = $query->nameadmin;
        $lastnameadmin = $query->lastnameadmin;
        /*////////////////////////////////////*/
    $data = array (
                'customer_number' => $customer_number,
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'name_en' => $this->input->post('name_en'),
        'father_name' => $this->input->post('father_name'),
        'number_birth_certificate' => $this->input->post('number_birth_certificate'),
        'national_number' => $this->input->post('national_number'),
        'passport_number' => $this->input->post('passport_number'),
        'term_passport' => $this->input->post('term_passport'),
        'date_of_birth' => $this->input->post('date_of_birth') ,
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'nationality' => $this->input->post('nationality'),
        'accommodation' => $this->input->post('accommodation'),
        'education' => $this->input->post('education'),
        'zip_code' => $this->input->post('zip_code'),
        'marital_status' => $this->input->post('marital_status'),
        'bank_name' => $this->input->post('bank_name'),
                'branch_name' => $this->input->post('branch_name'),
        'card_number' => $this->input->post('card_number'),
        'account_number' => $this->input->post('account_number'),
        'zip_code' => $this->input->post('zip_code'),
        'job' => $this->input->post('job'),
                'date_submit' => $jdate,
        'useradmin_submit' => $nameadmin.'&nbsp;'.$lastnameadmin ,
    );
    //if(!empty($data)){
        $this->db->insert('customer', $data);
        //}
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to debug the code in firebug? i can see you are getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: yes, i tried in firebug and chorme console, but The result was not

Comment: but i see same error that i said

Comment: what happens when you debug the server side code when the event happens, what is the 500 Internal Server Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to use this script I see the following error in the firebug's console:
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

This is the reason why error is showing up. Fix the server part.
Try to clean all the code inside search_customer() function and see if it runs. If this method never is executed then the problem is outside - in your framework?

Then, line by line see what is happening on the server. It can be problem with the query? But usually error 500 is when you have problem with mod_rewrite.

Comment: But there is file tour_foreign.php on server, why this link have error  500 (Internal Server Error? not this error on localhost and have same error that i said in top post

Comment: Try to insert die("this is test") in the first line of search_customer() then you will know where is the problem - you will know if the problem is coused by search_customer function or somethink outside